# Grab Multiple IPs from Remote Servers - ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

looking for some advice and if anyone knows if what I want to do is even possible.  Let me first explain the scenario.

**Main  WebServer**:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- .NET 4.0 Framework
- ASP.NET MVC3 Application

**Server Cluster (x10 Servers)**:

- Windows Server 2003/Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 6/IIS 7.5
- .NET 2.0+ Framework
- First NIC has one Physical IP address for server
- Second NIC has 10 Virtual IP adresses each one for a website in IIS Manager

What I am trying to do is to use the MVC3 website running on the Main WebServer to connect to the Server Cluster and return a list of Virtual IP addresses on each server and then store it in a MS SQL database.  Is this possible and can it be done through a .NET website?  I believe I can try writing a powershell script as each server has powershell 1+ on it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Fair question.  My team manages a large inventory of IIS WebServers and we're building a website to manage our inventory instead of using Excel.  We want an automated way of storing each available IP address on each webserver so we know how many additional websites we can deploy to it.

Comment: You *might* be able to use WMI to remotely query the server for IP Addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Erik.  I did some research based on your comment and have almost completed a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some code that uses WMI to find all of the IPs assigned to all NICs on a server.  You can look up the other fields available in the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note that this might not be fast enough to run live from a webpage.  I have something similar working, but I have a scheduled task go talk to all of my servers once a day.  Then the webpage just reads the info from a database.

Also note that this code assumes that the current user has enough access on the remote servers.  This is another reason to make it a scheduled task.  You can run the task as an admin to gather the data, and then a regular IIS user can read from the database.  Otherwise you'll have to change the user that IIS runs under to give it enough permissions.

```
// You'll need to reference "System.Management" for this to work...
var server = "your server name";
var scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"\\" + server + @"\root\cimv2");
scope.Connect();

using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope,
        new System.Management.ObjectQuery(
            "Select Caption, IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")))
{

    using (var children = searcher.Get())
    {
        if (children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
            {
                var nicName = item["Caption"];
                var ips = item["IPAddress"] as string[];

                if (ips != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(nicName);
                    foreach (var ip in ips)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("   " + ip);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Worked like a charm once I did something with the results.